# Same HTTP requests, different responses?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, webserver

I'm trying to run a Python script to request some webpages from a server. I'm using the requests library and pretty much using default arguments except for custom headers.

I've tested this in my main computer (lets call it A), which is running Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. Everything works fine and the responses from the server are correct.

Now, I've been trying to execute the same script in an old laptop at home that I use for this kind of stuff (lets call it B). I've replicated the same environment: same Python version, same packages. This laptop is running Debian 10.3 without a desktop environment.

Both A and B share the same public IP address because they are connected to the local network.

The issue is, requests sent by computer B are systematically identified as a bot and get blocked. I've tried this for several days and it's consistent: all requests from A work fine, all requests from B don't. I can even run both of them simultaneously and the behavior remains the same.

Now, this has me puzzled because:

- I understand that, from the webserver point of view, the requests from both A and B are identical: same request, same headers, same IP.
- The workload is clearly not a problem: I'm launching about one request every 10 minutes.

What could be the reason B is getting blocked but A is not?

Comment: "*same request, **same headers**, same IP*" - are you absolutely sure? Did you verify that, such as with a packet sniffer or debugging proxy?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your comment. Well, I'm sure my headers are set the same in both machines. I haven't checked with any of those tools. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: You may be setting your own headers the same on both machines, but you don't know if the requests library is setting its own headers the same on both machines.  You can use Wireshark if using plain HTTP, or Fiddler if using HTTPS.

Comment: I have used the http://httpbin.org/ to inspect the request received by the server: I can confirm that the web-server is receiving the same IP and same headers. Is there anything else you would suggest checking?

Comment: if that is true there is no possible way the server can differentiate one machine from another. Can you please [edit] your question to show the actual requests from both machines?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the 'requests' versions on both the machines and try out different versions.

I had the exact same problem. My local machine had requests 2.22.0 installed and it worked okay, but my VM had 2.24.0 installed, and the requests sent from there were unsuccessful.

Later I downgraded to 2.22.0 (on VM) and it worked like charm.